# Using javascript and node.js how to post the content to the text file through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Using javascript and node.js how to post the content to the text file through ajax.

```
<html>
<body>
     <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="postContent()">
  <script>
    function postContent(){
        var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('post','addContent.js',true);//in this sample.txt file i want to insert some content
        req.send();
      }

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

addContent.js

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/sample.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log("The file was saved!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a server-side script that writes the content to a text file and call that server-side script using Ajax.

```
req.open('POST', 'FilePoster', true);
req.send(dataToWrite);
```

Edited for new question:

```
req.open('post','addContent.js',true);
```

addContent.js should be an HTTP server running on a host and port.

If addContent.js is a node HTTP server, running on localhost and port 8080, the open call should be

```
req.open('POST', 'localhost:8080', true);
```

Comment: ok in server side script i have to write code to writes the content to a text file.